# Setting SharePoint Team Site Navigation Orientation and Visibility Programatically

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I'd like to be able to set a modern SharePoint Team Site's navigation orientation and visibility programmatically - either via a Site Template (modern) or via a REST API call that I can make from Power Automate.  I cannot find how to do this with either approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a SetChromeOptions method which you can use with a POST request:
_api/web/SetChromeOptions

Below is an example which sets the navigation to horizontal orientation.

```
{"headerLayout":2,"headerEmphasis":0,"megaMenuEnabled":false,"footerEnabled":false,"footerLayout":0,"footerEmphasis":0,"hideTitleInHeader":false,"logoAlignment":0,"horizontalQuickLaunch":true}
```

[image]

Comment: I see the orientation in this configuration, but I'm not finding a way to set overall visibility.  Which of the properties above set QuickLaunch visibility to false?

Comment: I tried using the payload below for setting the overall visibility. But my results have been inconsistent. Haven't figured out that boolean yet :)

{"headerLayout":2,"headerEmphasis":0,"megaMenuEnabled":false,"footerEnabled":false,"footerLayout":0,"footerEmphasis":0,"hideTitleInHeader":false,"logoAlignment":0,"horizontalQuickLaunch":false}